Can't reproduce React Fiber example on Expo in Android, but works fine on web
Very simple R3F model won't display on Android but will in web on same React Native project. Not my model -- just a simple boxGeometry. To make sure there were no dependency or config issues, I started a completely new Expo base app:
npx create-expo-app
cd my-app
npx expo install expo-gl
npm install three @react-three/fiber
npx expo start

The base app runs completely fine. Opens in Expo Go on my Android device and looks exactly as it should. So then I add in a simple boxGeometry same as in the 'getting started' example in Fiber docs:
<Canvas>
  <mesh>
    <boxGeometry />
    <meshStandardMaterial />
  </mesh>
</Canvas>

I'll put that after 'Step 1' in app/(tabs)/index.tsx of the base app. Then import { Canvas } from 'react-three/fiber' and npx expo start to run. If I run it in web, it looks as it should. I see a boxGeometry right there.But on the ExpoGo app on my Android device, it's just absent. No errors to debug or anything. Just not there. This is the same if I import from 'react-three/fiber/native' -- but in that case it doesn't work on web either.
